# Heroku docker spring boot image error 503 H14

Tags: spring-boot, docker, heroku, release, http-status-code-503

I few days ago I was trying to deploy a docker image of a spring boot app into heroku.

I have the following docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
LABEL maintainer="gabigarciagar@gmail.com"
VOLUME /tmp
COPY ./target/*.jar PetApp_Auth.jar
CMD [ "java","-Xmx300m","-Xss512k","-XX:CICompilerCount=2","-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8","-Dspring.profiles.active=heroku","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/PetApp_Auth.jar" ]
```

also in my application.properties for a heroku profile i have:

```
spring.profiles.active=heroku
server.port=${PORT}
server.servlet.context-path=/
```

then i execute the following commands and everithig looks nice:

```
$ heroku container:push petapp-authserver -a petapp-authserver
Your image has been successfully pushed. You can now release it with the 'container:release' command.

$ heroku container:release petapp-authserver -a petapp-authserver
Releasing images petapp-authserver to petapp-authserver... done
```

[image]

Also the heroku log show that the app is up and also heroku ps
the database connection is perfect also
[image]

```
$ heroku ps -a petapp-authserver
=== petapp-authserver (Free): java -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount\=2 -Dfile.encoding\=UTF-8 -Dspring.profiles.active\=heroku -Djava.security.egd\=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /PetApp_Auth.jar (1)
petapp-authserver.1: up 2020/03/06 21:09:51 +0100 (~ 1m ago)
```

Then when i try to see swagger-ui o /actuator/health i get the following:

```
2020-03-06T20:11:58.149484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=petapp-authserver.herokuapp.com request_id=e88c2499-b1de-4284-a649-1d8df19ae6c0 fwd="79.147.107.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-06T20:11:59.443315+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=petapp-authserver.herokuapp.com request_id=9fa4951a-365c-4b9b-bf63-94f8d6792249 fwd="79.147.107.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-06T20:12:08.185495+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/actuator/health" host=petapp-authserver.herokuapp.com request_id=c4c3382b-43b7-494c-9259-630ce24eb8a4 fwd="79.147.107.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-06T20:12:08.697245+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=petapp-authserver.herokuapp.com request_id=b044b6fe-ba8d-4b3d-8c7c-8e477ea7b609 fwd="79.147.107.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-06T20:12:12.943276+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/actuator/health" host=petapp-authserver.herokuapp.com request_id=6ac05b16-148d-4849-a857-c3d6bed9fe01 fwd="79.147.107.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-03-06T20:12:13.637589+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=petapp-authserver.herokuapp.com request_id=2c01dbaa-18c5-46f8-8f43-f91ee372a5eb fwd="79.147.107.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-03-06T20:12:23.492570+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/swagger-ui.html" host=petapp-authserver.herokuapp.com request_id=2850eb70-1bd5-4737-9505-d59184e95946 fwd="79.147.107.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-03-06T20:12:23.878827+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=petapp-authserver.herokuapp.com request_id=f83acdef-840a-4e2e-824c-183cfdc50273 fwd="79.147.107.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

as heroku web said https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running

i execute:

```
heroku ps:scale petapp-authserver=1 -a petapp-authserver
Scaling dynos... done, now running petapp-authserver at 1:Free
```

And same error

What I am doing wrong??

I was able to deploy the jar directly and it works

```
heroku deploy:jar PetApp_AuthServer-V-0.0.0.jar -a petapp-authserver
Uploading PetApp_AuthServer-V-0.0.0.jar
-----> Packaging application...
       - app: petapp-authserver
       - including: PetApp_AuthServer-V-0.0.0.jar
-----> Creating build...
       - file: slug.tgz
       - size: 46MB
-----> Uploading build...
       - success
-----> Deploying...
remote:
remote: -----> heroku-deploy app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 96.8M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v12
remote:        https://petapp-authserver.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
-----> Done

2020-03-13T19:25:13.683982+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/auth/login" host=petapp-authserver.herokuapp.com request_id=ef9a29b6-c10c-4b82-8088-711d448c3a32 fwd="88.17.74.86" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=362ms status=200 bytes=878 protocol=https
2020-03-13T19:25:13.780163+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/fonts/titillium-web-v6-latin-600.woff2" host=petapp-authserver.herokuapp.com request_id=f2f6334d-2663-49b0-bd28-b5d287e79b68 fwd="88.17.74.86" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=12634 protocol=https
```

Why it perfecty works with jar deploy and not with docker??

I have also tried:

```
Gabi@MSI MINGW64 /d/Proyectos/PetApp/Back/PetApp_AuthServer (develop)
$ heroku container:release web petapp-authserver -a petapp-authserver
 !    Expected response to be successful, got 404

Gabi@MSI MINGW64 /d/Proyectos/PetApp/Back/PetApp_AuthServer (develop)
$ heroku container:release web petapp-authserver -a petapp-authserver
 !    Expected response to be successful, got 404

Gabi@MSI MINGW64 /d/Proyectos/PetApp/Back/PetApp_AuthServer (develop)
$ heroku container:release petapp-authserver -a petapp-authserver
Releasing images petapp-authserver to petapp-authserver... done
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, it is not because of spring security I have configure it to allow suchs endpoints

Comment: Please include `heroku.yml` in your question. If you follow my answer it will get rid of the H14 No web dyno running error: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running

Comment: heroku ps -a petapp-authserver

=== petapp-authserver (Free): java -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount\=2 -Dfile.encoding\=UTF-8 -Dspring.profiles.active\=heroku -Djava.security.egd\=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar (1)
petapp-authserver.1: up 2020/03/13 19:55:28 +0100 (~ 6m ago)


heroku ps:scale petapp-authserver=1 -a petapp-authserver
Scaling dynos... done, now running petapp-authserver at 1:Free

Same error

Comment: Is your error just with swagger and actuator? What happen with other rest controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solved the question.
The point is that the image in heroku must be named same as the process type, in this case web!

so there are two options. Build and pushing the image by using:

```
heroku container:push web -a petapp-authserver
```

or create the image locally and the tag it as registry.heroku.com/petapp-authserver/web

```
docker tag petapp-authserver registry.heroku.com/petapp-authserver/web

docker push registry.heroku.com/petapp-authserver/web
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/petapp-authserver/web]
eb03575d1edf: Preparing
ceaf9e1ebef5: Preparing
9b9b7f3d56a0: Preparing
f1b5933fe4b5: Preparing
eb03575d1edf: Layer already exists
9b9b7f3d56a0: Layer already exists
f1b5933fe4b5: Layer already exists
ceaf9e1ebef5: Layer already exists
latest: digest: sha256:4c0ae2bba092c07bbd89394216b0bf78f458ba3583e63c8d15e01f6b07d6933e size: 1159

heroku container:release web -a petapp-authserver
Releasing images web to petapp-authserver... done
```

Now my containers are perfectly running in docker!!

[image]

[image]

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

In your `Procfile` or your `heroku.yml` you have not specified a `web` worker.

```
2020-03-06T20:12:23.878827+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=petapp-authserver.herokuapp.com request_id=f83acdef-840a-4e2e-824c-183cfdc50273 fwd="79.147.107.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

For containers you should use `heroku.yml`. `Procfile` might even be ignored.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml

Doing this will get rid of your current H14 errors.

Comment: where I should store that heroku.yml file? within the container? adn why I can not just build the image with just The dockerFile? if I add the heroku.yml file, the commands and procedure I have been usisng should be the same?. The point is that my git repo contains a los of Back spring boot microservices in the same repo, for me it is easier than having 12 repos with each one of the microservice, does it will affect to deploy on heroku? sorry for my english

Comment: It needs to be in the root folder of your git repo. The dockerfile itself does not specify the process type. There are 2 processes on Heroku. A web process with where you get an assigned `$PORT` and anything else which is basically just a process without any exposed port. You can try run the command `heroku container:release web -a petapp-authserver` and see if you are still getting H14 errors.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime. https://medium.com/@urbanswati/deploying-spring-boot-restapi-using-docker-maven-heroku-and-accessing-it-using-your-custom-aa04798c0112 The heroku.yml I hve ridden that it is used for heroku build containers usisng the repo, but i dont want that!, i dont want to use my git repo as I said

Comment: I have update the post because with jar deployment it works perfect without any heroky.ymal file or similar

Answer (score 1):

Key point is the process type.

For example, when you deploy the jar and runs it, you can see at your logs:

```
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
```

But you don't see it when using release because you haven't specified a process type.
Can you try to run the release command like this and see if it works?

```
heroku container:release web petapp-authserver -a petapp-authserver
```

**web** is the process type!

Comment: $ heroku container:release web petapp-authserver -a petapp-authserver
 !    Expected response to be successful, got 404

Comment: $ heroku container:release petapp-authserver -a petapp-authserver
Releasing images petapp-authserver to petapp-authserver... done

Comment: It seems the process must be declare in another way